# Powershell multiple If-Statements with loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, arraylist, powershell-2.0

I have to check for multiple array entries in an if statement.

```
if (($Right.IdentityReference -eq $User) -or ($Right.IdentityReference -eq ("Domain\" + $GroupArrayList[0])) -or ($Right.IdentityReference -eq ("Domain\" + $GroupArrayList[1])))
```

This will continue with $GroupArrayList[2], $GroupArrayList[3], ...

Is there any way how I can go trough every entry of the array? I can't write every position down because the array size is dynamic. How can I create such a loop?

Comment: `$array | Where-Object { 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' -contains $_.IdentityReference }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Foreach`

```
Foreach ($ArrayItem in $GroupArrayList) {
    if (($Right.IdentityReference -eq $User) -or ($Right.IdentityReference -eq ("Domain\" + $ArrayItem))) {
        # Do stuff
    }
}
```

The variable `$ArrayItem` will refer to your $GroupArrayList[2], $GroupArrayList[3],...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you even need a loop for that, but instead use the `-contains` operator like this:

```
if (($Right.IdentityReference -eq $User) -or ($GroupArrayList -contains ($Right.IdentityReference -replace '^Domain\\',''))
```

You simply strip off the `Domain\` from the `$Right.IdentityReference` and see if the string that remains can be found in the `$GroupArrayList` array.

Answer (score 1):

As you're `OR`ing the comparison's why not testing if `-in` array?

```
if ($Right.IdentityReference -in 
        $User,
        ("Domain\" + $GroupArrayList[0]),
        ("Domain\" + $GroupArrayList[1]) ) {
```